# Injecting a map of std::string and StrictMock<MockClass> into a class under test

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a class that routes buttons to respective workers. My workers are under test and I now need to get my router under test. The problem is that my router is unable to take in the map of mocks like I would initially expect it to. A lot of the code is stripped out but I believe the following code should be enough to produce the same result.

The router constructor signature is as follows:

```
ButtonRouter::ButtonRouter(std::map<std::string, WorkerInterface*> in_map)
```

I created a mock as follows:

```
class MOCK_WorkerInterface : public WorkerInterface
{
    MOCK_METHOD(void, doSomething, (), (override));
}
```

I tried creating a map of mocks for the router as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>*> my_map;

StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>* worker_1 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();
StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>* worker_2 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();
StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>* worker_3 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();
...

my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_1", worker_1));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_2", worker_2));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_3", worker_3));
...

ButtonRouter* button_router = new ButtonRouter(my_map);
```

When running the test I get that there is no matching function call for the `ButtonRouter`'s constructor to be passed in a map of MOCK_WorkerInterfaces. Is there an issue with passing in mocks like this? Should I just directly inject them into the constructor rather than to a map then to the constructor?

Comment: `I get that there is no matching function` Please post the verbatim and complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wrong declaration

```
std::map<std::string, StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>*> my_map;
```

should be

```
std::map<std::string, WorkerInterface*> my_map;

auto* worker_1 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();
auto* worker_2 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();
auto* worker_3 = new StrictMock<MOCK_WorkerInterface>();

my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_1", worker_1));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_2", worker_2));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair("worker_3", worker_3));
```

Comment: This worked. I guess i thought that the underlying compiler would convert the type from the mock to the worker interface type. Thank you